# Where to Place the Image in Gallery for Image Uploading so that it can be Uploaded to Server

Tags: android, gallery, httpserver

This is about Uploading a image in a folder on a server with given IP Address. I have created UI but don't Know where to Place Image so that I can Uploaded it From Gallery.

On clicking Upload Button, "Please select a Image" appear, Moving to Gallery by selecting "Gallery "but as Gallery is empty NO media Found is Displayed, But How and where to Place Image in Gallery? and what are the Changes to be Done in Program and all files to upload to a server, I am using Eclipse indigo and new in Android world.

Any help will be highly Appreciated.

Comment: can anyone help me with Code Snippet on Connecting to server with IP address stated.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the image to be opend by every app you should place it in

```
/sdcard/Android/data/"your apps package name"/
```

if you want the galllery to find it and list it as gallery content 
save it to

```
/sdcard/"some folder"/
```